# How to make printwriter output to .txt remember multiple data entries

Tags: java, output, printwriter, data-entry

I am making a simple program to input some data (Name, A Game, an Achievement Score and Minutes played) and whenever I input one piece of data (max of 100) it only remembers the last one inputted

https://i.gyazo.com/d4a51acc564fb459b9e590c7474700d8.png

I wanted it to remember all entries in a list

```
        try
        {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("Gamer Report Data.txt");
            writer.println("Player : " + gamerName);
            writer.println();
            writer.println("--------------------------------");
            writer.println();
            String[] report = gamerReport.split(":");
            writer.println("Game: " + report[0] + ", score= " +report[1] + ", minutes played= " +report[2]);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("File does not exist!");
        }

        }



    }

    public static char[] getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public static void setInput(char[] input) {
        JavaProject.input = input;
    }

}
```

Comment: Pick a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+printwriter+append

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open your `PrintWriter` using a [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)) with append set to true

Comment: I have added this with the append set to true however the same thing happened with the overwrite of data https://gyazo.com/d43e88003bc564e95af42c67c00e605e

Comment: The `FileInputStream` goes inside the `PrintWriter` constructor

Comment: `new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(file, true))`

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried it and it works fine for me. Did you input 2 entries?